# Kafka Connect: how to parse String to Map

Tags: json, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

Let's suppose I have a file filled with `JSON` objects/lines separated by new line characters (`\n`). When a *FileStreamSource* based connector would read this file it would consider each line as `java.lang.String`.

How could one parse this `java.lang.String` to a `java.util.Map` or [struct](https://kafka.apache.org/0100/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/connect/data/Struct.html) in order to perform further transformations (e.g. mask a field using *MaskField* or extract a field using *ExtractField*)?

PS: the question is not about how to parse some `java.lang.String` to a `java.util.Map` or [struct](https://kafka.apache.org/0100/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/connect/data/Struct.html) but about how to integrate such parsing logic with Kafka (a custom Kafka transformation?) or obtaining the same result by other means (e.g. configuring something in Kafka or using a specific connector/transformation, etc)

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible ways:

1. You could use the Confluent Platform and run your connector with an appropriate KSQL query (https://docs.confluent.io/current/ksql/docs/tutorials/index.html#ksql-tutorials).
2. You could spin up a Kafka Stream app (https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/streams/) along with a your Source connector. The stream app will read messages from the topic/-s in which your connector puts messages. You need to implement your transformation logic in the Kafka stream app. When message is processed the Stream app puts it to an output topic. Below is a sample structure of the stream application code.

```
Properties props = new Properties();

...

final StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(<YOUR_INPUT_TOPIC_PATTERN>);
KStream<String, String> source = builder.stream(pattern);

...

source.mapValues((k,v) -> {
     Gson gson = new Gson();
     Map map = gson.fromJson(v, Map.class);

     // here is your transformation logi

     return v;
}).to(<YOUR_OUTPUT_TOPIC>);

...

final Topology topology = builder.build();
final KafkaStreams streams = new KafkaStreams(topology, props);

...

streams.start();
```

Comment: This is just java code; how this relates to Kafka Connector? Do you suggest that this code should be part of a custom transformer which to be used with e.g. the source connector?

Comment: @adrhc Yes, you'd need to take something like this code and build your own transformer

Comment: @adrhc, to avoid customizing a source or sink connector you could spin up a simple Kafka Stream and get the new messages with extracted field/-s you need.

Comment: @dmvkl - what do you mean by "get the new messages with extracted fields"? I can't get fields from a String, that's the whole issue.

Comment: @dmvkl - please elaborate your answer or delete it because is nothing else but some java code showing how to parse a JSON String which is not the issue I try to solve

Comment: @adrhc, you had been provided with the answer to your original question. I've edited my answer, hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: I don't understand how KSQL approach helps here; please elaborate.

Comment: what kind of transformation do you want to perform?

Comment: Could you provide more details of your problem?

Comment: I would like e.g. to parse some text to a specific java class (e.g. Map), but could really be anything else. I agree Kafka Stream is a solution but a Kafka transformation seems more straightforward. I don't understand how the KSQL part would help.

Answer (score 0):

As the Apache Kafka documentation says, `FileStreamSource` is not exactly a production supported connector...

Perhaps you'd be better off using the spooldir connector, which does support line delimited JSON https://github.com/jcustenborder/kafka-connect-spooldir/blob/master/README.md

Comment: The question is about getting from `java.lang.String` to a `java.util.Map` or `struct` but not to getting data from a file or else.

Comment: Your question is about using Connect in general, no? So my answer is - use a different Connector which supports what you are asking for

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [Mask Json Field Transform](https://ferozedaud.blogspot.com/2023/06/mask-json-field-transform-kafka-connect.html) for kafka connect. This can read your JSON text and mask fields inside it. It can be used in a Source or a Sink Connector.